# Private constructor and android.app.Instrumentation issue

Tags: java, android, singleton

In my app, I have implemented a Token class as a singleton to handle user's identification. However, when I launch my app, it fails with the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   appliflo.Token: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: private
>   appliflo.Token() is not accessible from class
>   android.app.Instrumentation

I am wondering weather this could be due to the Application class inheritance.

**Here is my singleton:**

```
package appliflo;
import android.app.Application;

public final class Token extends Application{

    private static long TokenID;
    private static Token instance;

    private Token(){

    }

    private Token(long TokenID){    
        this.TokenID = TokenID;
    }

    public static synchronized Token getToken() { 
        if (instance == null) instance = new Token();
        return instance;   
    }

    public static synchronized void setToken(long id){
        if (instance == null) instance = new Token(id);
        instance.TokenID = id; 
    }

    public long getTokenID(){    
        return this.TokenID;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exception message states the class `android.app.Instrumentation` cannot create an instance of your application because it cannot access its constructor since it is private.

You need to have a public constructor that has no parameters in order to allow the Android system to create an instance of it to start your application.

You will not be creating an instance of `Token` yourself so the static methods `getToken` and `setToken` will not be useful.

**Update for question in comment:**

If you need to update the tokenId update your get and set methods to only update the long and not create a new instance of your `Token` class.

```
public static synchronized long getToken() {
    return TokenID;
}

public static synchronized void setToken(long id){
    TokenID = id;
}
```

Comment: But if I want to modify the variable TokenID (every time the login is modified), I will need to use the setToken id method no?

Comment: Technically speaking, can my Token class be still considered as a singleton (considering your update)?

Comment: Yes there should only ever be one instance of your application class at a time created for you by the Android system. You can set things up to keep a static reference to it but there are still some things you need to be aware of as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

Comment: Do I need my Token instance anymore?

Comment: Not if all you need is the `TokenID` from it.

Comment: However, I do not see what can prevent multiple Token instance in my app, and how to keep track of the unique instance along my app...

Comment: It seems that my first approach should work according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517702/singleton-in-android

Comment: That will not work again because you do not control the creation of the Application. Android creates the Application for you in the `android.app.Instrumentation` class listed in your exception using `Application app = (Application)clazz.newInstance();`. Look up the documentation on `newInstance` and you will find it uses the default no args constructor. Since you made the default constructor private the `Instrumentation` class cannot access it and a `IllegalAccessException` is thrown.

Comment: Do you understand now?